# Why is Angular Flex Layout defaulting to small window view?

Tags: angular

I've created a product feed that I want to use Flex Layout for, however, for some reason it appears to default to the view as if it were on a small device, despite currently being on a standard laptop window. The HTML for my layout is:

```
<div class="content" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap" fxFlexFill>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts | async">
            <div fxFlex="33" fxFlex.xs="33">
                <h3>{{ product.productName }}</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Colour: {{ product.colour }}</li>
                    <li>Brand: {{ product.brand }}</li>
                    <li><button (click)="openDialog(product.productID)">Add to Pad</button><li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
```

Image from the browser:

[image]

The expected behaviour is for all 3 to appear on the same row for all windows except for mobile view, where it will appear as a column view.

Live example: https://padder-939bc.firebaseapp.com/catalogue

Comment: Can you add your code to https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @GermanQuinteros I'm using firebase hosting for the product data so that makes it difficult to add to stackblitz, but I've added a live link to the page to the question which should be similar enough?

Comment: Yes, it's enough. Now I can see the project. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the Angular Flex-Layout directives are not being applied:

[image]

If the Angular Flex-Layout directives were being applied we should see `display: flex` instead of `display: block`

If I add manually the `display: flex` property the code works like you are trying to do:

[image]

Did you import the `FlexLayoutModule` in the Module where your component has been declared?

Comment: It's often the small things we overlook.. I've been using a module to import / export everything centrally, however, I've noticed that this has been within another part of the code and not the part this page references. I overlooked this as I thought it was being imported elsewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

The expected behaviour is for all 3 to appear on the same row for all windows except for mobile view, where it will appear as a column view.

Comment: is there a link to documentation?

Comment: i mean, "can you put a link to documentation in your answer"?

Comment: should i put it in the word document?

Comment: You can edit the answer, and add a public url to it, pointing to the relevant docs.  See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info on what make a high-quality answer.